# Find the Page Urls

Tags: php

I have  page and I don't show a specific block to a specific urls.
So my urls are *www.example.com/products/product1.html*, *www.example.com/products/product2.html* etc..
So what I want to do. I want to find all the urls that starts with www.example.com/products/ and in those urls, exclude the block.
So far my code for one url is:

```
<?php
$a = "www.example.com/products/product2";
$p = curPageURL(); ?>
<?php
 if($a == $p ){ 
    Dont show the block
?>
```

But I have 100 urls that I don't show the block.
Is there any change to do for all the urls without write 200 lines of code?

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Your page? Any page? What kind of 'blocks' are you talking about?

Comment: Sounds repeatable.. for loop?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question about the block and the page. I don't want to show an image to a specific urls.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

This function will check if the specified string exists in the URL and if it exists, do not show the block.

```
$findme = 'www.example.com/products/';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === FALSE) {
  // SHOW BLOCK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `strpos()`

```
$cururl= "http://.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pos = strpos($cururl, '/products/');
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
  // products found do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php)-function like this:

```
$blockedUrlArray[] = "www.example.com/products/product2";
$blockedUrlArray[] = "www.example.com/products/product3";
.
.
.
$searchUrl = curPageURL();

//if the current Url is not in blocked Urls
if(!in_array($searchUrl, $blockedUrlArray){
//do something 
}
//if the url is a blocked url
else{
//do something 
}
```